# DataTables not displaying content for a simple example

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

Here's the JSON, returned by the web service call, which is successful.

```
{"items":[{"version_no":"7.6.5.4"}]}
```

And here's my javascript / HTML. When I load the page, it displays the header and footer properly, and makes the call out to the web service. But it doesn't display the version number contained in the JSON.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Page 1</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <style type="text/css" class="init">

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="lib/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="lib/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="lib/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#example').DataTable( {
      "ajax": {
         cache: true,
         url: "https://<hostname>/get_version/",
         type: "GET"
      },
      "columns": [
         { "data" : "items.version_no" }
    ]
   } );
} );
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
<p>
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:"75%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Version</th>
        </tr>            
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Version</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here's what the browser displays

[image: Browser output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, DataTables expects data returned from AJAX-call formatted in a certain way (array of arrays or array of objects, where each entry corresponds to table row, enclosed, by default, within property data/aaData).

However, if you need to override this behavior, you may use [`dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) property of `ajax` option to point to your `items` property:

```
ajax: {
   ...
   dataSrc: 'items'
}
```

After that, you may simply refer to `version_no` within column definition:

```
columns: [{data:'version_no', title:'Version'}]
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that was it! I don't know how long it would have taken me to figure that out, much appreciated.